# Will blender 2.8 official realise be able to run on computer with graphics driver that is lower then OpenGL 3.3

Tags: workflow

I have seen videos on the upcoming blender vision 2.8 and I would also like to expand with blender like everyone. I hope the developers won't let my laptop limits to keep me from developing my skills.

Thank you

Comment: nope, but if you are okay with blender 2.79 you shouldn't worry about it

Answer (score 1):

It will not. As [stated on the official page](https://www.blender.org/2-8/), minimum requirements demand at least a minimum supported [OpenGl Version of 3.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#OpenGL_3.3).

A consensus was reached that this was required to allow supporting all new and upcoming features features of EEVEE viewport. This includes realistic graphics and high visual fidelity, higher viewport performance, better use of resources and take advantage of modern hardware and new graphics cards features, without many compromises for newer hardware.

Unfortunately this means dropping support for older cards and more dated hardware.

- For AMD cards, [versions prior to HD 2000 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_HD_2000_Series) (circa 2007) are no
  longer supported
- For NVidia cards this means [cards older then the GeForce 8 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#GeForce_8_(8xxx)_series) (G##8000 circa 2010) are no longer supported
- For Intel integrated graphics cards you must have at least [sixth generation IGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Sixth_generation), generally on a i# 2#### processor or newer

Unfortunately if you have hardware older than the above mentioned cards, or that somehow doesn't support OpenGL 3.3 you won't be able to run version of Blender newer than 2.8#. You can try to upgrade your drivers to the newest supported version (unlikely, but some times support was later added to older cards).

You can always run versions from 2.79 and prior.

Comment: Hi, nVidia GTX 780 will be fine?

Comment: If it supports CUDA, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an older system doesn't support OpenGL 3.3 now it's unlikely 'upgrading your drivers' would fix it. Staying on to stick Blender 2.79 isn't a good answer because you'll be denied bug fixes and UI improvements.

You either need to buy a new system or switch to Maya or Max both of which have good legacy support for older OpenGL and free educational licenses for students.

Comment: You'd suggest using Maya or Max over blender 2.79? I'm not worried about using a legacy version (I still use CS4). If it works, no reason to abandon software just because a new incompatible version came out.

Answer (score 0):

**The Mesa Alternative:**

I had the same issue.  Tried installing newer drivers (which is always the best option) but the manufacturer's download link was corrupted.  I'll keep checking back, but what do I blend till then!??

Therefore, I needed an alternative.  Enter our old open-source OpenGL alternative [Mesa 3D](https://mesa3d.org/).

To make it happen, either [build it yourself](https://mesa3d.org/README.WIN32) or if you're lazy like me, [download pre-built binaries](https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win/releases).  (The mingw version from that page worked great on my Win7 x64 Intel i3000 graphics card.)

Simply unzip file into your Blender install directory, and viola! :)